# Fill vector with alphabets depending on user input and put Start and End on the extremities

Tags: c++, vector, iota

I am trying to make a vector to look like this:
alphabet= {start,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,etc..,end}

The alphabet doesn't go from A to Z, the user inputs the values.
So if user inputs 5, I want the vector to be:
{start,A,B,C,D,E,end}

I tried using iota but I don't know how to push the "start" and "end" at the extremities of the vector

```
vector<string> alphabet;
iota(alphabet.start(), alphabet.end(), 'A');
```

How to push the `start` and `end` values?

Comment: Can you please post more detailed input-output example? You declared a vector of strings yet you want to store letters? Of which type are `start`,`end` variables? Writing `alpahbet.end()` twice is a typo? You might want to look at [`std::back_inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) as STL functions do not resize containers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the first 5 letters of alphabet

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <numeric>

int main() {
  // vector needs to be allocated, +2 is for start and end
  std::vector<std::string> alphabet(5+2); 
  // front() gives you reference to first item
  alphabet.front() = "start";
  // end() gives you reference to last item
  alphabet.back() = "end";
  // you can use iota, but skipping the first and last item in vector
  std::iota(std::next(alphabet.begin()), std::prev(alphabet.end()), 'A'); 

  for (const auto& S : alphabet)
    std::cout<<S<< ", ";
}
```

Output of this block of code is: `start, A, B, C, D, E, end,`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
int numberOfLetters;
std::cin >> numberOfLetters;
std::vector<char> characters(numberOfLetters);
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfLetters; i++)
{
    characters[i] = 65 + i;
}
```

This will work, because chars use ASCII encoding, and "A" has an ASCII value of 97, and it increases from there, so 65 + 0 = 'A', 65 + 1 = 'B', and so on. (Of course include vector to have access to std::vector, or use a C array, as this: `char* characters = malloc(numberOfLetters);`

A note here: you don't need to use the number 65, you can write 'A' like this:

```
characters[i] = 'A' + i;
```

as the characters can be added, because they can be represented as numbers. (suggested by churill)

Comment: You might as well use `'a'` instead of 97, better to read.

Comment: Yeah, I actually haven't thought of that, I prefer to use numbers when adding characters (or even hex rather then decimal, but decimal is better for readability), but I'll update it

Comment: OP already knows how to get a vector containing the letters, the question is how to add "start" and "end" to that